# Associativity of cartesian product in Univalent Foundations

Tags: homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

In classical set theory, pairs $(x,y)$ are encoded usually in such a way that (for sets $A,B,C$)
$(A\times B)\times C \neq A\times (B\times C)$. 
From my (small) knowledge of Univalent foundations, objects do not carry "extra information" (such that $1\in 2$...), my question is thus :

Do we have equality $(A\times B)\times C = A\times (B\times C)$ in the setting of Univalent foundations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $X$ and $Y$ are types, the univalence axiom provides a way to construct a witness of the equality $X = Y$ given any equivalence $\varphi\colon X\simeq Y$. Isomorphisms of $X$ with $Y$ give in particular equivalences of $X$ with $Y$. It hence suffices to construct $f\colon (A \times B) \times C \to A \times (B \times C)$ and a function $g$ in the other direction such that $f$ and $g$ are pointwise inverses of each other.

But this is possible due to the definition of (or the axioms for) product types of the form $X \times Y$. For this product type we know:

1. For terms $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$, we may construct a term $(x,y)\in X\times Y$
2. We have functions $\pi_1 \colon X \times Y \to X$ and $\pi_2 \colon X \times Y \to Y$ such that for all $p \in X\times Y$ we have $p = (\pi_1(x),\pi_2(y)).$

Hence I'm allowed to define $f\colon (A \times B) \times C \to A \times (B \times C)$ by $(p,c) \mapsto (\pi_1(p),(\pi_2(p),c))$. This is the usual isomorphism, for which one constructs the usual pointwise inverse $g$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using the same argument, can we prove that $A\times B=B\times A$, since there is a function $f$ and another $g$ in the other direction that are pointwise inverses of each other from $A\times B$ to $B\times A$ ?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I guess I don't really understand how this can be compatible with "usual" set theory, since normally $A\times B\neq B\times A$ since $(-1,1)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{N}$ but $(-1,1)\notin \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Phil-W: It's still true in homotopy type theory that $(-1, 1) \not\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}$. If you know that $X = Y$ (in your example it's $A \times B = B \times A$), that is if you have a value $p : (X = Y)$, then you can *transport* any value of $X$ to a value of $Y$, "along $p$". Normally it's perfectly okay to not mention $p$ explicitly in the notation. For instance, in ordinary mathematical practice, most people are content to say that $\mathbb{R}^4 = \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2$ and that, if $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $(v,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4$. *...continued...*

Comment: Even though, of course, this is not strictly speaking true in usual set theory. An implicit transport takes place! Namely we employ the isomorphism $((a,b),(c,d)) \mapsto (a,b,c,d)$. The only difference in homotopy type theory is that isomorphisms are promoted to equalities; but we still need to transport along witnesses of equality. The confusion arises because the witness given by the isomorphism $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$ has a more complicated feel to it than the isomorphism $((a,b),(c,d)) \mapsto (a,b,c,d)$ which merely reassociates the parentheses.